# How to stop animation loop of this code in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$("#RUN").focusout(function() {
if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    $.post('index.php?User=CheckUser', { "UserName": $("#RUN").val() }, function(result) {
        // Var's
        var OrigMsg = $("#RUI").text();
        var OrigColor = $("#RUI").css("color");
        // Code
        $("#RUI").slideUp(1000);
        $("#RUI").delay(500).queue(function(next) {
            $(this).empty();
            $(this).css("color", result.color);
            $(this).append(result.message);
            next();
        });
        $("#RUI").slideDown(1000).delay(3000).slideUp(1000);
        $("#RUI").delay(500).queue(function(next) {
            $(this).empty();
            $(this).css("color", OrigColor);
            $(this).append(OrigMsg);
            next();
        });
        $("#RUI").slideDown(1000);
    }, "json");
}
});
```

Every time I go out of the item with ID #RUN it animates, I tried to set:

```
$("#RUN").focusout(function() {
    $("#RUN").stop();
});
```

And all the stop combinations: stop(true), stop(true,true)

Also tried:

```
if ($("#RUN").is(":animated")) {
    $("#RUN").stop(true,true);
}
```

And all the stop combinations.

I don't really know very well where to put the .stop() thing for this to stop animation loop.

EDIT:
The HTML code is:

```
<td>
    <input type="text" id="RUN" name="RUN" maxlength="30" />
</td>
<td>
    <div id="RUI" class="InfoItem">
        Letras y Numeros, longitud minima 8 caracteres.
    </div>
</td>
```

As for the jsFiddle is a little difficult to make because it uses the $.post() and for now I only have the page on my local PC.

Comment: I highly suggest that you post some HTML to go with this. And a jsFiddle would greatly help us to help you!

Comment: Basically what i want to do is a user checker, it checks if the username is already registered and if is ok with my requirements, and this output's a string, if it is available the color is green else the color is red, but for example I type Archangels in the input, then change to another one go back to the input and type BlaBlaBla it shows me User is not available (for Archangels) and I have to wait all the animation until it says User is available (for BlaBlaBla), and also has a animation loop if I trigger focusOut event more than 1 time.

Comment: Does it ever reach the statement ``$("#RUI").slideDown(1000);``?

Comment: yes, the code is functional, but if I do focusOut let's say 5 times it animates 5 times with the same code lets say that take 30sec to animate, well mean while I chage the user name and focusOut, I have to wait the 30 sec and the code to animate the 5 times, and after that I will see the new results, that is what i am trying to avoid.